# Circle().scaleEffect() In ForEach Won't Draw If Scale Is Less Than 1 With A Computed Scale

Tags: swiftui

Can someone tell me why this code does not return four circles in a `VStack`, with the largest being full size, and the smallest at 25% of full size? How do I get this without using four separate circles? And no, it doesn't work with the `.frame()` inside the `ForEach`

[image: Image of 4 views in a Stack, with only the bottom one having a circle]

```
struct MultipleCirclesView: View {
    let maxSize: CGFloat = 100
    let count: Int = 4
    let color: Color = Color.red
    let borderLineWidth: CGFloat = 8
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(0..<count) { current in
                Circle()
                    .strokeBorder(color, lineWidth: borderLineWidth)
                    .scaleEffect(CGFloat((current + 1) / count))
            }
            .frame(width: maxSize, height: maxSize)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try wrapping current, count, and 1 separately in CGFloat. Sometimes there is some weird rounding behavior

Comment: Definitely the right track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a fix - type fixed:

```
Circle()
    .strokeBorder(color, lineWidth: borderLineWidth)
    .scaleEffect(CGFloat(current + 1) / CGFloat(count))   // << here !!
```

*Note: `scaleEffect` does not change view's frame - only drawing.*

[image: demo]

Comment: Yep, that works. So, just for future reference, after testing, dividing an `Int` by an `Int` returns an `Int` that is rounded? I tested that theory and want to confirm it.

Comment: Int / Int = Int, so 2 / 4 = 0